# Do-while loop inside a method

Tags: java, loops

Everything is working fine in this code sample that i did, but everytime it calls the do-while loop on the output screen, it skips the "First name" input, and goes straight to "How old are you?" input. why is that happening and how can i fix it? I want to be able to repeat the whole thing without skipping "First name" when i pick 'y' to perform the loop.

```
public class WeightGoalTest
    {
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {

            doWhile person = new doWhile();

            person.userInput(); 
        }
    }

    import java.util.*;

    public class doWhile
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        private String inputFn = "";
        private int inputAge = 0; 
        private int inputHeight = 0;
        private double inputWeight = 0.0;
        private int inputCalculation = 0;
        private int inputGender = 0; 

        private char loop; 

        public void userInput()
        {

        do
        {
            System.out.println("First Name: ");
            inputFn = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("How old are you?");
            inputAge = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Gender 1 - Male: ");
            System.out.println("       2 - Female: ");
            inputGender = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("What is your Height in inches? ");
            inputHeight = keyboard.nextInt(); 

            System.out.println("Current Weight in pounds: ");
            inputWeight = keyboard.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("\nDo you want to use the calculator again? (y/n)");
            loop = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        }while(loop == 'y');

        }
    }
```

Comment: Classes in Java are **always** in `PascalCase`. Please stick to Java naming conventions if you post code here, and probably in general too.

Answer (score 1):

Please note:

- **String java.util.Scanner.next() - Returns:the next token**
- **String java.util.Scanner.nextLine() - Returns:the line that was skipped**

Change your code [do while initial lines] as below:

```
    System.out.println("First Name: ");
    inputFn = keyboard.next();
```

Comment: Olab - Could you please change your code and confirm this fits?

Comment: Rajesh - Confirmed! thank you it worked

Answer (score 0):

use `keyboard.next()` instead of `.nextLine()`. For further informations have a look in the Java API concerning the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. `nextLine()` will

> Advance this scanner past the current line and return the input that was skipped."